# How to doPastBack on an AJAX Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting a html page with GET and it contains this element:

```
<a id="ctl00_cphRoblox_ClaimOwnershipButton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphRoblox$ClaimOwnershipButton','')">Claim Ownership</a>
```

I want to do the action in the `href` attribute

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var hrefValue = document.getElementById("ctl00_cphRoblox_ClaimOwnershipButton").href;

var hrefSplit = hrefValue.split("'");

var hrefArgument = hrefSplit[1];

__doPostBack(hrefArgument);
```

1. Extract the `href` attribute from the anchor.
2. Split the href by `'` separator, which makes an array like:

   `["javascript:__doPostBack(", "ctl00$cphRoblox$ClaimOwnershipButton", ",", "", ")"]`
3. Take the 2nd item (index 1)
4. Execute the function (which I guess never changes) with the extracted argument.

Comment: Well I can't help you with that without knowing about your environment.